# change image based on increment parameter

Tags: jquery, image, parameters, increment

i'm building a website here
and i'm struggling for something that bothers me
i'm trying to make a increment button that will change image depends on the increment parameter
for example if the value is'0', the picture is 'a'
then i increment it, the value is '1, and the picture is 'b' and so on
i did some code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Image Change Demo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function increaseValue ( eleId ) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(eleId);  
  ele.value = parseInt(ele.value) + 1;}
  function decreaseValue ( eleId ) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(eleId);
    if(ele.value!=0){
      ele.value = parseInt(ele.value) - 1;
  }};
 function changeIt(imageName,objName)
   {
var obj = document.getElementById(objName);
var imgTag = "<img src='"+imageName+"' border='0' />";

obj.innerHTML = imgTag;

return; 
   };
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="image1">
  <img src="1.jpg" border="0" alt="" /> 
 </div>

 <br><br>

 <input type="text" value="1" id="incrementer" />
 <input type="button" value="+"    onclick="increaseValue('incrementer'),changeIt('button/next.png','image1');">
 <input type="button" value="-"  onclick="decreaseValue('incrementer'),changeIt('button/plus.png','image1');">
 </html>
```

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple solution with jQuery could be the following:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    var currentValue = $(":text").val();
    var symbol = $(this).val();
    if(symbol == "+") {
        currentValue++;
        $(":text").val(currentValue);
    }
    else {
    currentValue--;
        $(":text").val(currentValue);
    }
    $("img").hide();
    $("img:eq("+(currentValue-1)+")").show();
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="image1">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=2.jpg" border="0" alt="" /> 
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=3.jpg" border="0" alt="" />  
 </div>

 <br><br>

 <input type="text" value="1" id="incrementer" />
 <input type="button" value="+">
 <input type="button" value="-"">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KQP99/

Comment: thanks a lot
but why i can't make it work ?
i'm only changing the img src but the increment don't work

Comment: @Kevin phytagoras this reason I want the demo, to check what is wrong

Comment: hey, it's working, but what i did is same as you
could it be because onLoad ?
here if you want to check it
http://jsfiddle.net/Ub3Et/1/